# SQL remove text before a given string (shortening URL to URL Path)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to remove text in URLs so that a URL like https://www.nike.com/w/nike-free-5-shoes-3apemzy7ok would becomes /w/nike-free-5-shoes-3apemzy7ok

or https://www.kohls.com/search/mens.jsp becomes /search/mens.jsp

I can't use a RIGHT function, as there are multiple different domains, so the amount of characters it has to move changes from a case to case basis.

Does anyone know how to write a SQL query that can support this effort?

What I was thinking was something that looks for the ".com" and uses a wild card to remove ".com" + everything before the ".com"

That said, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this after a fair amount of research.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, NET.HOST(url) || '[^/]*/(.+)')
```

You can test, play with above using sunny data as in example  below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'https://www.nike.com/w/nike-free-5-shoes-3apemzy7ok' AS url UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://www.kohls.com/search/mens.jsp' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'www.Example.Co.UK/1/2/3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'www.Example.Co.UK:80/1/2/3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://www.Example.Co.UK:80/1/2/3' 
)
SELECT url, 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, NET.HOST(url) || '[^/]*/(.+)') path
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

```
Row url                                                     path     
1   https://www.nike.com/w/nike-free-5-shoes-3apemzy7ok     w/nike-free-5-shoes-3apemzy7ok   
2   https://www.kohls.com/search/mens.jsp                   search/mens.jsp  
3   www.Example.Co.UK/1/2/3                                 1/2/3    
4   www.Example.Co.UK:80/1/2/3                              1/2/3    
5   https://www.Example.Co.UK:80/1/2/3                      1/2/3
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the URLs defeat the logic of "find the first slash after the first double slash" you could:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(url, CHARINDEX('/', url, CHARINDEX('//', url) + 2)) + 1, 9999)
```

In English this is "substring starting (just after the index of the first slash in the url starting from just after the index of the first double slash) and a length longer than the rest of the string (= take to the end of the string)

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, you can use `regexp_extract()`:

```
select regexp_replace(url, '^.*//[^/]+/(.*)$', '\\1')
from (select 'https://www.nike.com/w/nike-free-5-shoes-3apemzy7ok' as url union all
      select 'https://www.kohls.com/search/mens.jsp' 
     ) x;
```